# Docker - how to use a saved file created in the container

Tags: python, docker

**Objective**: train a machine learning model in a `.py` (`train_model.py`) file, save the model to a `.joblib` file (`Inference_xgb.joblib`), load the model into another `.py` (`Inference.py`) file, use the model to make predictions and save the output.

**Issue**: `Inference.py` cannot find the `Inference_xgb.joblib` file.

**Relevant code snippets**:

Training (`train_model.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from joblib import dump

def train():
    # load in and read training data
    training = './train.csv'
    data_train = pd.read_csv(training)
    label = data_train['2020 Failure'] # what we want to predict
    features = data_train.drop(['2020 Failure', 'FACILITYID'], axis =1, inplace=False) # what we train on the model to learn
    features = features.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
    x_train = features
    y_train = label

    # XGBoost model training
    xgb_model = XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric="logloss")
    xgb_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    # save model
    dump(xgb_model, 'Inference_xgb.joblib')

if __name__== '__main__':
    train()
```

Testing (`Inference.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
from joblib import load
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import os

def inference():
    # load and read in test data
    testing = './test.csv'
    data_test = pd.read_csv(testing)

    label = data_test['2020 Failure'] # what we want to predict
    features = data_test.drop(['2020 Failure', 'FACILITYID'], axis =1 ) # what we train on the model to learn
    features = features.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
    IDS = data_test['FACILITYID']
    x_test = features
    y_test = label

    # run model
    xgb_model = load('Inference_xgb.joblib')
    y_label = xgb_model.predict(x_test)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_label)
    print("Confusion Matrix: ")
    print(cm)

    # write results
    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    print('CURRENT PATH: ', dirpath)
    output_path = os.path.join(dirpath, 'output.csv')
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(y_label, columns=['Prediction'])
    output_df.insert(0, "FACILITYID", IDS.values)
    output_df.to_csv(output_path)
    print('OUTPUT DF')
    print(output_df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inference()
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook 

RUN pip install joblib
RUN pip install xgboost==1.5.0

USER root

WORKDIR /scaleable-model

COPY train.csv ./train.csv
COPY test.csv ./test.csv

COPY train_model.py ./train_model.py
COPY inference.py ./inference.py

RUN python3 train_model.py
```

**Comments, observations, and what I've tried**:

I've noticed that removing `WORKDIR /scaleable-model` fixes the issue, but I want to keep the `WORKDIR` to `/scaleable-model` so I can mount the `.csv` output to my host machine.

I am running `docker build` in the `scaleable-model` directory on my host machine. That is, I cd to `/home/user/pathto/scaleable-model` and run `docker build -t scaleable-model -f Dockerfile .`

I then call `docker run` and specify I want to call `Inference.py`, this is how the error is generated.

I've tried hardcoded paths as well but this did not help. I also created a `Inference_xgb.joblib` on my host machine in the same directory where I am building the container, but this did nothing either.

I suspect that either:

- the `Inference_xgb.joblib` file is not being created properly in the container
- I am messing up the directory structure somehow inside the container and thus `Inference.py` cannot find the file.

To quote Michael Burry, "I guess when someone's wrong, they never know how". I'd like to try to understand the how here.

EDIT:
Checking the contents of the container, the file (`Inference_xgb.joblib) IS being created in the directory that I want (`/scaleable-model`). Therefore, it must be an issue with` Inference.py` not detecting the file for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

To verify if the model file is being created in the container, you can -

- Create a container and start a bash terminal

  `docker run -it <image_name> bash`
- Check the current directory - this should be `scalable-model`

  `pwd`
- List the contents of the directory - this should show the model file

  `ls`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks like the model IS being created - thus it must be something wrong with my directory structure.

Comment: After you start a bash terminal in the container, run the inference from the terminal using `python inference.py`. Since you are already in the `scalable-model` directory, you should be able to run it. If there is no error, then the directory structure should be fine. When you are calling docker run to execute the inference, I'm assuming you are using this command - `docker run <image_name> python inference.py`.